# sessions files in cache/frontend/prod/test

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I don't need sessions, nor cache of the output in my application, but sessions files are created in cache/frontend/prod/test. How to turn it off?

```
cache/
└── frontend
    ├── dev
    │   ├── config
    │   ├── i18n
    │   └── template
    └── prod
        ├── config
        │   ├── config_app.yml.php
        │   ├── ...
        │   └── modules_inapppurchasevalidation_config_security.yml.php
        ├── i18n
        ├── template
        └── test
            └── sessions
                ├── 14c4d82c8934772e6450fa749f6901d3.session
                ├── 19438fe227ad428f2ebcf9aefae222f9.session
                ├── 1d24195a28026f623fd4bb48a39c6d37.session
                ├── 287d5460dbff1fb1fe48b8ca4b4ac2d5.session
                ├── 2a74fb0e218a965661286f3ac2e59dd3.session
                ├── 2ad682cfbda63ce45288020d03df551f.session
                ├── 43bb9a06ce37f8600d3ec53ae0f17373.session
                ├── 53e1834564a25ab70fb7583094b99c53.session
                ├── 632c81aaa893435ccd9d82ffd7970133.session
                ├── 698b11253e8b17cec56d9c58938579bb.session
                ├── 70a13c61da15e8a71d02634ecb0f5db1.session
                ├── f3a0d8aff2dd49da763b7a5186502748.session
                ├── f8a25a6a69d8bcedfffbdb2e469781c4.session
                ├── fa639b23b103812d460d1fe57fe02785.session
                ├── fa95efd3cb1563fe0cab1500ed803901.session
                └── fdbd2255efc01d7f17ed1d3895a16bb8.session
```

The content of these files is like this: a:5:{s:31:"symfony/user/sfUser/lastRequest";i:1320407937;s:33:"symfony/user/sfUser/authenticated";b:0;s:31:"symfony/user/sfUser/credentials";a:0:{}s:30:"symfony/user/sfUser/attributes";a:0:{}s:27:"symfony/user/sfUser/culture";s:2:"en";}

factories.yml:

```
prod:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: err
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
test:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionTestStorage
    param:
      session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions
  response:
    class: sfWebResponse
    param:
      send_http_headers: false

  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none
dev:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none
all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true

  view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true

  storage:
    class: sfSessionTestStorage
    param:
      auto_start: false
      session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions
```

settings.yml:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        true
    cache:                  false
    etag:                   false
all:
  .settings:
    escaping_strategy:      true
    escaping_method:        ESC_SPECIALCHARS
    use_database:           true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `factories.yml` you have this configuration:

```
test:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionTestStorage
    param:
      session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions
```

Which means: "in the `test` environment, save all sessions (using the `sfSessionTestStorage` in the designated path).
If you don't need any session storage while in the `test` environment, set class to `sfNoStorage`. You can leave the `param` part then, because the `sfNoStorage` provider doesn't have any settings.

If you don't need any sessions in your entire application, you can remove the part under `test:`, and configure everything under `all:`. 
(Did you know you already assigned the same `sfSessionTestStorage` under this block? From a performance point of view you shouldn't use the `sfSessionTestStorage` too much...)

Comment: I found the answer, but you brought even more information! Thanks for sharing with sfNoStorage and keeping all the settings under all!